# XMLHttpRequest.open() causing mixed content warning

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, opera, sony

This is on a sony TV browser which is using Opera 12.  I stopped it in a debugger and as soon as the xmlhttp.send() gets called, the warning shows up on the TV: "this page contains both secure and non-secure items.  Would you like to continue?"

I can't, for the life of me, figure out why that would cause that error, before it even gets a response.  This is all done on https.

request in this instance is: https://COMPANYURL/vendors/vendor/stores?zipcode=80002&limit=10

```
MicroServiceDataSource.prototype.fetchReply = function(request, successCallback, errorCallback) {
    var that = this;
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {
        // code for IE6, IE5
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", request);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + btoa(SceneManager().appConfigModel.microserviceUsername + ":" + SceneManager().appConfigModel.microservicePassword));
    xmlhttp.send();
    //error happens here ^^^
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                var replyObj = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                that.handleSuccess(replyObj, successCallback);
            }
            else {
                that.handleReadyError(xmlhttp, errorCallback);
            }
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: Open that link in a browser ... firefox for example complains _oururl.com uses an invalid security certificate. The certificate is only valid for bp.unify.com (Error code: ssl_error_bad_cert_domain)_

Comment: You and SO have bad SSLs

Comment: @JaromandaX didn't mean to confuse, that's not the real url, didn't want to give up too much information since this is for work.  The certificates are valid on our site.

Comment: @Jesse What do you mean?

Comment: are you going from http to https or vice versa?

Comment: @epascarello no I made sure everything is https.  Strangely, I get the error if I load the page on http OR https.